# In python3, what is called when a number is referenced?

Tags: python-3.x

When you assign a variable to an integer, what code is ran? Overwriting the 'int' class doesn't change it. For example:

```
class int2(int):
    def __init__(self, inp):
        print("test")
        super().__init__(inp)

int = int2
a = 2
```

Doesn't print "test", any ideas?

Comment: You are missing `()`, as in `int = int2()` -  and don't use `int` as your variable name.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid OP is trying to replace the `int` type itself.